# How to create a highlighted calendar using LaTex?

Tags: calendar, latex, pdflatex

I am not looking for a GANTT planning.
I am looking for a calendar with the deadline on it.

Do you know what is the best way to do that with LaTeX ?

Thanks

Comment: Create tables, with deadline being one of the columns?

Comment: ::Reads question this time:: Damn! Mea, culpa. Not a duplicate at all. ::hangs head in shame:: Deleting that comment and going to bed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want a simple calendar with a deadline circled, you can do so easily with [Tikz](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pgf/).  From their [documentation](http://www.texample.net/tikz/builds/):

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\calendar (mycal) [dates=2000-01-01 to 2000-01-31,week list];
\draw[red] (mycal-2000-01-20) circle (4pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

gives

```
                 1 2
 3  4  5  6  7  8  9
10 11 12 13 14 15 16
17 18 19 20 21 22 23
24 25 26 27 28 29 30
31
```

with a red circle around `20`.

The manual has examples of some pretty complicated calendars as well.